# Foreign key violation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys

I have 3 models in rails and their relations are an user belongs to one group but can join many project inside of a group.

Model User:

```
belongs_to: group
has_many :members
has_many :joined_projects, through: :members, source: :project
```

Model Project:

```
has_many :members
has_many :project_members, through: :members, source: :user
```

Model Group:

```
   has_many :users
   has_many :projects
```

I got an error when I run the code to add user into a group

```
 @group.users << @user
```

I keep saying me that `Invalid Foreign Key/ Foreign key violation. Insert or update on table users violates the foreign key constraint key(group_id = 17 is not present in table project`
I do not get it since I just run a code to update the group_id in the user table, but some how it does relate to the table project . Any helps ?

Comment: Foreign keys are a database level concern and actually have nothing to do with your assocations. Check your database schema. The first line in your users model is also a syntax error.

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks !